# Does every quartic polynomial of the form $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$ where $a \neq b \neq c \neq d \neq 0$ have a distinct local and absolute minimum?

Tags: functions

To me it seems like yes because it's composed of 4 linear factors so it would have four roots.  Also it's not negative fourth degree, so therefore has two convex lumps in the function.  Perhaps there's functions where the convex lumps go to the same y-value but I think they should be predictable right, or do they even exist?

Comment: what if $a=b=c=d=0$?

Comment: Fixed that oversight :p

Comment: What about $(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$, where the minima are the same?

Comment: So are they predictable?   I'm sure they are more rare, so could I form a statement that says which ones would always have unique absolute and local mins?

Comment: the problem is that the first derivative is a polynomial in degree $3$ and we have the parameters $$a,b,c,d$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try. I'm assuming that by $a\neq b\neq c\neq d\neq 0$ you mean that the $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all distinct and also different from 0.

The fact they are distinct is relevant, the fact they are different from 0 is not, since we can always "translate" the polynomial setting $x' = x+k$ and the graph does not really change. So in the following I'm going to disregard that condition.

Since this is a polynomial with 4 distinct roots, degree 4 (even) it is clear that it also has 2 local minima and one local maximum between the roots (which are $-a$, $-b$, $-c$, $-d$).

If the roots are symmetrical with respect to a central point $m$, i.e., if the polynomial is of the form $(x+m+a)(x+m-a)(x+m+b)(x+m-b)$ then clearly the graph is symmetric with respect to $x=m$ and thus the two local minima coincide in high. The derivative in that case is $2 (m + x) (2x^2-a^2 -b^2 + 2 m^2 + 4 m x)$  so it is not difficult to find where it is zero, apart $x=-m$.

So, now we want to understand if it possible for our polynomial to have the value of the two minima coincident when the roots are not symmetric with respect to a middle point $m$.

We can assume w.l.o.g. that the derivative has 3 roots, say $v_1<v_2<v_3$, it is equal to $p(x)'= k(x-v_1)(x-v_2)(x-v_3)$. Taking the indefine integral we can find the general form of a polynomial was derivative is $p(x)'$.

We obtain (multiplying by a suitable constant to get a $x^4$ with coefficient 1) something of this form:
$$
p(x) =  x^4-(4/3)\left( v_1+ v_2+  v_3\right)x^3  +
   2\left(  v_1 v_2+  v_3 v_2+  v_1
   v_3\right) x^2 -4  v_1 v_2 v_3 x+h\,,
$$
where $h$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now, we want to impose that the value in the two local minima coincide, i.e., that $p(v_1) = p(v_3)$ for the $p(x)$ above. It turns out that we should have $v_1=v_3$ (that we excluded) or $v_2=(v_1+v_3)/2$.

So now we can plug $v_2=(v_1+v_3)/2$ in the polynomial above and we obtain 
$$
p(x) = x^4-2\left(v_1+ v_3\right) x^3+\left(v_1^2+4
   v_3 v_1+v_3^2\right) x^2-2v_1v_3\left( 
   v_1+ v_3\right) x+h.
$$

Now we can solve $p(x)=0$ to see if the solutions (aka $-a$, $-b$, $-c$, $-d$ in the original expression) are or not symmetric.

We obtain
$$
x_{1,2,3,4}=\frac{1}{2} \left(v_1+v_3\pm\sqrt{v_1^2-2 v_3
   v_1+v_3^2\pm 4 \sqrt{v_1^2
   v_3^2-h}}\right)
$$

and it is easy to see that in pairs the solutions sum up to $v_1+v_3$, so they are symmetric.

In conclusion, if I have not made some horrible and/or stupid mistakes, the only case in which the 2 local minima of $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ with all the $a,b,c,d$ distinct, can have the same value is when the roots are symmetric with respect to a middle point.